# Adding a horizontal line in CSS stylesheet (for XML file)

Tags: css, xml, dtd, horizontal-line

I am very new to the world of coding, so please bare with me.
For a school project we are encoding a humanities text document.
I have my XML and DTD files completed - XML editor states these are both well formed.
However, I want to include a horizontal line (or bottom border?) dividing the title of the text and the main body. How can I do this simply?
I have tried many tutorials and it will not render when opening on Google Chrome.

Excuse my lack of knowledge - but I'm assuming I need whatever the element name is for the line within my XML (and therefore my DTD) as well?

Comment: Please include the code you have tried - we are unable to help you if you don't show us the code and explain why it didn't work.  Also, this may help you with adding styles to xml - https://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html.

Comment: Is this part of your school project requirements? Has your instructor taught you about XSLT, by any chance?